# Name (or proof) of $\frac{a}{b} - 1 = \frac{a-b}{b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

Can someone tell me **the name of the equation (or the proof)** which I show here:

> The equation is always valid:
>
> $$\frac{a}{b} - 1 = \frac{a-b}{b}$$

I used $(a-b)/b$ to calculate the difference in percentage between $a$ and $b$. But it seems, that I can also use $(a/b) - 1$ (which return always the same result).

Comment: Get a common denominator.

Comment: I doubt this particular equation has a name, as it's an extremely simple rewrite of an expression as a single fraction.

Comment: No official name for this? Most people tend to use the roundabout `(a-b)/b` to calcualte the **percentage difference**, I think because they are not aware of the elegant equivalent equation `(a/b) - 1`.

Comment: I agree with @Randall ... you can call it "common denominator" if you need a name.

Comment: @nimo23 why is one "roundabout" and the other "elegant"?   This is just subtracting fractions as in grade school.

Comment: @Randall yes, I know this equation quite a while but I did not find a name for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just $\frac{a}{b}-1=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{b}{b}=\frac{a-b}{b}$ as @Randall mentioned.